# tensorflow.data.Dataset.from_generator() converts string arguments to bytes

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset

I have a custom generator which takes two dates in string format as arguments and yields (features, labels) from within the date range. I want to create a dataset out of it, but `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()` stubbornly converts date strings to bytes causing the generator function to fail. Let me demonstrate this behaviour:

```
def some_generator(date1, date2):
    print(date1, date2)
    yield [1, 2], [3]

feats, label = next(some_generator('2010-01-01', '2017-12-31'))
signature = (tf.type_spec_from_value(tf.convert_to_tensor(feats)),
             tf.type_spec_from_value(tf.convert_to_tensor(label)))
ds = Dataset.from_generator(some_generator, args=('2010-01-01', '2017-12-31'), output_signature=signature)

for feats, label in ds.take(1):
    print(feats, label)
```

The output from this code is:

```
2010-01-01 2017-12-31
b'2010-01-01' b'2017-12-31'
tf.Tensor([1 2], shape=(2,), dtype=int32) tf.Tensor([3], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
```

The first line is the result of the first call to `some_generator` where feats and label are generated for the signature, and here the dates are printed out as strings.

The second line is the result of iterating over the dataset in the for loop and there the dates are printed as byte strings. This problem does not occur with integers, but I need strings. If anyone has an idea how to solve this please share.

Comment: Having the same issue, is it a bug or not? Shall we report it?

Comment: May be worth a try now that there is two of us.

Comment: This bug seems to be known but hasn't been fixed yet.  https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38409

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution that I came up with is to decode the arguments if they are not strings, ie.:

```
def some_generator(date1, date2):
    date1 = date1 if type(date1) == str else date1.decode('ASCII')
    date2 = date2 if type(date2) == str else date2.decode('ASCII')
    print(date1, date2)
    yield [1, 2], [3]
```

which with the rest of the code from the example above produces:

```
2010-01-01 2017-12-31
2010-01-01 2017-12-31
tf.Tensor([1 2], shape=(2,), dtype=int32) tf.Tensor([3], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
```

So it does solve the problem, but adds extra computations, because the conditional checks end type conversions are done for every generated data sample which is not ideal.